# C++ filling two dimensinal array with zero's

Tags: c++

```
int  ** b;

b = (int **)(new int[5 * 12]);

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
        b[i][j] = 0;
    }
}
```

I'm getting `access violation` error in the row `b[i][j] = 0;`

Where am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Same problem: the code defines `int **b`, stores a value into `this->b`, and access the `b` that was defined at the top.

Comment: ahh, ok. my mistake. corrected again.

Comment: the problem is [i][j] means i*row_length+j. But there is no row_length defined in this example. You should either change how to access individiual elements, or create an array on the stack.

Comment: Thank you Seckin, your help's just solved my problem.

Comment: @EnesUnal you should check Nick's answer, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `b` has type `int**`, the expression `b[i]` points to the offset `sizeof(int*)*i` and `(b[i])[j]` adds the offset `sizeof(int)*j`. In total you are accessing a byte at offset `sizeof(int*)*i + sizeof(int)*j` which is not at all identical to the offset `sizeof(int)*(i*j)` which would be used to determine the the index in your flat one dimensional array.

You are requesting a one dimensional array but treating it like a two dimensional array. That cannot work. As usual casting is to blame.

Answer (score 2):

Your code allocates the memory in `b`, but that's not what you try to set later. Instead you try to set `b` which is unallocated.

Answer (score 1):

`b` is uninitialized, so accessing through it produces undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The real problem is that if you use *b* as a 2d array without specifying one dimension, the compiler doesn't really know how to index its access, try to write it like this:

```
int  (* b)[12];
b = new int[5][12];
```

What we do here is declare *b* as a pointer to a 12 element array, so when we index on the *i* index, the compiler knows that it must multiply by 12.

Comment: I cannot change int** so I solve my problem with the answer which I'm posting now.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the cast, then figure out what type you want to allocate and what type of variable to store it in. The cast is hiding a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is `[i][j]` means `i*row_length+j`. But there is no `row_length` defined in this example. You should either change how to access individual elements, or create an array on the stack.